# How to write and update a user score that is stored in a textfile in c#?

Tags: c#, text-files

I am making a quiz game for my A level computing coursework. The quiz works fine, but the problem is that at the end of the quiz I want to save the users score and username to a text file. I have already tried to search for the answer both on Stack Overflow and other websites, but I couldn't find an answer.

At the end of the quiz I have a form called EndForm and when that form loads, I call a method called `SaveScore()`. The code is down below. I want this method to save the username and score of the user in the scores.txt file. I also want the users score to be updated if the user replays the quiz and gets a higher score. I don't know why my current code is not working.

```
    private void SaveScore()
    {

        string file = @"..\..\textfiles\scores.txt";

        FileStream fileStream;
        StreamWriter streamWriter;

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                string[] HighScore = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToArray();
                string[] contents = new string[] { };
                File.WriteAllLines(file, contents);

                 fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                 streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                for (int i = 0; i < HighScore.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] HighScores = HighScore[i].Split('~');

                    string username = HighScores[0];
                    int currentScore = Convert.ToInt32(HighScores[1]);

                    if (player.Score > currentScore)
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(player.Name + "~" + player.Score);

                        for (int x = i; x < 4; x++)
                        {
                            string[] newHighScore = HighScore[x].Split('~');

                            string newUsername = newHighScore[0];
                            int newScore = Convert.ToInt32(newHighScore[1]);
                            streamWriter.WriteLine(newUsername + "~" + newScore);
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(username + "~" + currentScore);
                    }

                    streamWriter.Close();
                    fileStream.Close();
                //Write player score data to file if it is not already there.

                    if (HighScore.Length < 10)
                    {
                        fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                        streamWriter.WriteLine(player.Name + "~" + player.Score);

                        streamWriter.Close();
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error saving high score", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't update a textfile easily. Just rewrite the whole file.

Comment: This is way too broad. Narrow down your problem, 'not working'  is not helpful... what exception you are getting?

Comment: the problem is that this method is not writing or updating the users score or username into the scores text file

Comment: Modify your code: First: Read all Lines into a Dictionary<string, int> (where string is your username and int is your score). Second: If the current user does not exist, add a new entry, if the current user exists check if the new score is higher. Third sort the dictionary descending on the score. Fourth: Then write max. 10 records to file. Break up the complete task to simple, small pieces of code you can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do everything you need - if you have any questions just ask. May I also suggest using a CSV rather than a text file? Simply change the extension.

```
private void SaveScore()
{
    String scoresFilePath = @"..\..\textfiles\scores.txt";

    try
    {
        //
        // Create file if not exists
        //
        if (!File.Exists(scoresFilePath))
        {
            File.Create(scoresFilePath).Dispose();
        }

        //
        // Create DataTable
        //
        DataColumn nameColumn = new DataColumn("name", typeof(String));
        DataColumn scoreColumn = new DataColumn("score", typeof(int));

        DataTable scores = new DataTable();
        scores.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
        scores.Columns.Add(scoreColumn);

        //
        // Read CSV and populate DataTable
        //
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(scoresFilePath))
        {
            streamReader.ReadLine();

            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                String[] row = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                scores.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        Boolean scoreFound = false;

        //
        // If user exists and new score is higher, update 
        //
        foreach (DataRow score in scores.Rows)
        {
            if ((String)score["name"] == player.Name)
            {
                if ((int)score["score"] < player.Score)
                {
                    score["score"] = player.Score;
                }

                scoreFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //
        // If user doesn't exist then add user/score
        //
        if (!scoreFound)
        {
            scores.Rows.Add(player.Name, player.Score);
        }

        //
        // Write changes to CSV (empty then rewrite)
        //
        File.WriteAllText(scoresFilePath, string.Empty);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("name,score");

        foreach (DataRow score in scores.Rows)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(score["name"] + "," + score["score"]);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(scoresFilePath, stringBuilder.ToString());
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error saving high score:\n\n" + ex.ToString(), "Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to swallow the exception and you should get a useful error message. Change:

```
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error saving high score", "Error");
}
```

to

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error saving high score: " + ex.ToString(), "Error");
}
```